# Script for Dropdown Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryng to fix this function to show alert on dropdown.
Where am I wrong? Alert does not appear.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function () {
    $( "#species" ).change(function(){
    if ( $(this).children(":selected").val() == "" ) {
    alert("empty");
    }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

FORM:

```
<form>
<label for="species" id="species">*Species:</label><br />
<select id="species" name="species" size="1">
<option value="">Please choose a species</option>
<option value="21">Chicken</option>
<option value="28">Turkey</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having 2 events and the 2nd is being bound on the click event.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function () {
    if ( $("#species" ).children(":selected").val() == "" ) {
       alert("empty");
    }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: 1. You have the same id for your **label** as you do for your **select** element which confuses jQuery.

1. You bound your click event to the change event on the selectBox which is not necessary.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function (e) {
       if($('#species').find(":selected").val()===""){
         alert("empty");
       }    
       e.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6SuvK/